# Regex match pattern with optional character and min/max length

Tags: regex, grep

Match starts with X, which is followed by 3 to 6 capital words or numbers, must containt at least one letter and can have optional dash -.
Example of matches:

```
XABC
XA-BC8D
X-ABC
XB72D-
```

Example of non-matches:

```
X123      //no letters
XAB       //too short
XABC-123  //too long
XA--BC    //too many -
```

I tried with `X(?=.{3,6}$)[A-Z0-9]*-?[A-Z0-9]*`, but it has many problems. It can match something like `X---`. Regex should be compatible with grep.

Comment: The first `x` can be lowercase, right?

Comment: Sorry, it should be capital, I edited it now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use this regex with `gnu grep` using `-P` (PCRE):

```sh
grep -P '^X(?!([^-]*-){2})(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])[A-Z\d-]{3,6}$' file

XABC
XA-BC8D
X-ABC
XB72D-
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NDFeYV/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `X`: Match letter `X`
- `(?!([^-]*-){2})`: Negative lookahead to assert that there are never more than one hyphens ahead
- `(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])`: Positive lookahead to assert presence of at least one uppercase letter ahead
- `[A-Z\d-]{3,6}`: Match an uppercase letter or digit or `-` 3 to 6 times
- `$`: End

---

If you don't have `gnu grep` installed then you may consider this `awk`:

```sh
awk -F- 'NF<3 && /^X[A-Z0-9-]{3,6}$/ && /.[A-Z]/' file

XABC
XA-BC8D
X-ABC
XB72D-
```

Comment: May I ask how the negative lookahead works in this example and why it doesn't need `{2,}`

Comment: Yes sure, fel free to ask any question here. `(?!([^-]*-){2})` works because it fails as soon as it finds 2 hyphens in input. It doesn't need to match more than 2 hyphens for failing the assertion.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `grep` with a PCRE pattern using `-P` option (or `pcregrep` if `grep` is not available):

```sh
^X(?!(?:[^-]*-){2})(?=.*\p{Lu})[\p{Lu}\d-]{3,6}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XWSjTR/1). Details:

- `^` - start of string
- `X` - an `X` char
- `(?!(?:[^-]*-){2})` - there can't be two not necessarily consecutive hyphens in the string
- `(?=.*\p{Lu})` - there must be an uppercase letter in the string
- `[\p{Lu}\d-]{3,6}` - three to six alphanumeric or `-` chars
- `$` - end of string.

Here is a way with `awk`:

```sh
awk '/^X[[:upper:][:digit:]-]{3,6}$/ && /.[[:upper:]]/ {val=$0; sub("-","",val); if (val ~ /^X[[:upper:][:digit:]]+$/) {print $0;}}' file
```

A bit shortened version:

```sh
awk '/^X[[:upper:][:digit:]-]{3,6}$/ && /.[[:upper:]]/ {val=$0; sub("-","",val); val ~ /^X[[:upper:][:digit:]]+$/}1' file
```

See an [online demo](https://ideone.com/JBoi64). *Details*:

- `/^X[[:upper:][:digit:]-]{3,6}$/ && /.[[:upper:]]/` - the line must contain an uppercase letter that is not first in the string, and must match the `^X[[:upper:][:digit:]-]{3,6}$` pattern:

  - `^` - start of string
  - `X` - a `X`
  - `[[:upper:][:digit:]-]{3,6}` - three to six alphanumeric or `-` chars
  - `$` - till end of string
- `val=$0; sub("-","",val);` - the line is assigned to `val` variable and then a single `-` is removed from `val`
- `if (val ~ /^X[[:upper:][:digit:]]+$/) {print $0;}}` - if the `val` starts with  `X` and then has only uppercase letters or digits till end of string, print it. In the shortened version, that `if $0 ~ /.../ {print $0;}` is replaced with `/.../` and `1` flag (that by default prints the whole record (line).